# JS, появление и исчезание блоков, delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно реализовать появление блоков через определенный промежуток (не одинаковый), при этом чтобы одновременно с появлением третьего блока пропадал первый, с появлением четвертого блока пропадал второй и т.д. Таким образом на экране одновременно должно быть только два блока. Я написал такой скрипт:

```
$(function(){
  $('#1').delay(1000).show(400);
  $('#2').delay(2000).show(400);
  $('#1').delay(3000).hide(400);
  $('#3').delay(3000).show(400);
  $('#2').delay(4000).hide(400);
  $('#4').delay(4000).show(400);
  $('#3').delay(5000).hide(400);
  $('#5').delay(5000).show(400);
});
```

Но почему-то таймер срабатывает неправильно. По логике первый блок должен скрыться перед показом третьего, но он скрывается только после показа четвертого. В общем тут лучше один раз увидеть - [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcqjkj1k/)

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, вот такой код работает как нужно:

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#1').show(400);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#2').show(400);
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#3').show(400);
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#1').hide(400);
    $('#4').show(400);
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#2').hide(400);
    $('#5').show(400);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1">Один</div>
<div id="2">Два</div>
<div id="3">Три</div>
<div id="4">Четыре</div>
<div id="5">Пять</div>
```